PSA : Taiwan's Ministry of Education's 國語辭典 comprises mistakes
I thought to blazon this warning.

I use 國語辭典 often but would not call it "authoritative." It contains a lot of mistakes. Be aware of this fact when consulting the dictionary. I might still keep the email in which I asked them to change "天涯笑此時" to "天涯哭此時". – joehua Sep 2 at 7:47

By the bye, I'm not targeting Taiwan's Ministry of Education or Taiwan. Don't hesitate to edit this post to blazon other faulty dictionaries.

This is anecdotal at best, I'm failing to see any sort of evidence that backs up the claim.

@Mou某 The said dictionary doesn't contain an entry for 徹底. It has 澈底 which, I believe, means "(water is so clear you can) see to the bottom." This is different than 徹底, which means (doing things) all the way to the end. The dictionary says 澈底 meas all the way to the end and it can also be written as 徹底. I don't agree with it.

a dictionary has a mistake, or mistakes, is normal.
similar anecdotes in english dictionaries:

dord defined as a term in physics and chemistry meaning density

http://www.english-for-students.com/Dictionary-Makers.html

physics lecturer has spotted a 99 year old mistake in the oxford english dictionary

http://topnews.co.uk/24144-physics-lecturer-spots-99-year-old-mistake-dictionary
more in oxford english dictionary:
https://wordhistories.net/2018/01/16/errors-oxford-english-dictionary/
imo, no sensible man / woman would discredit the oed, after these errors :)
